# Android Emulator Crashes on ig4icd32.dll with exception code c0000005 (emulator-arm.exe has stopped working)

Tags: android, android-emulator, crash, emulation

I have been developing apps on Android for a while now. I have the development environment installed on my laptop and everything was working till this morning. I had the v15 and v10 SDK platforms and emulators installed.

Just to try the Android Jelly Bean emulator, I tried to download the v16 SDK from SDK Manager. That led to a series of updates in SDK manager and then the ADT plug in also. Since that I have been facing this issue whenever I try to start the emulator. I have searched a lot and tried all of the following methods but the error still persists. I have a Intel Core 2 Duo laptop with the Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family graphics card. The latest driver version 8.15.10.2555 is installed now.

1) Uninstalled the newly installed Jelly Bean v16 SDK components.

2) Uninstalled and reinstalled Android SDK and ADT plugin.

3) Updated my graphics driver.

4) Tried number of combinations of AVD settings (camera off, gps off, accelerometer off, resolutions, RAM size, SD card size)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was able to finally get my emulator working by removing Android SDK, ADT Plugin completely. Then I reinstalled Android SDK using the starter package of rev 15 (versus the latest one available from google). It appears that there is some incompatibility with the latest SDK and my graphics driver. Still waiting for a solution for the same....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I was able to make this work using a workaround posted on the web...

Just go to the /tools/lib and rename the file libOpenglRender.dll to something else like rename libOpenglRender.dll.bak....

You should be good. The emulators start working....

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion cant run device without thats file!

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my android sdk and emulator and faced same issue, so
uninstalled emulator and sdk tools v26
Use emulator in android sdk tool <= 25.2.3 (extract and copy to sdk folder)
Download and update intel haxm for android to v6.1.2.
It worked for me