# emulator-arm.exe has stopped working

Tags: android, android-emulator

What am i going to do if my emulator has stopped working?

It displays this in the problem details:

```
Problem signature:
    Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
    Application Name:   emulator-arm.exe
    Application Version:    0.0.0.0
    Application Timestamp:  5111a505
    Fault Module Name:  ig4icd32.dll
    Fault Module Version:   8.15.10.2057
    Fault Module Timestamp: 4b5e41aa
    Exception Code: c0000005
    Exception Offset:   00032930
    OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
    Locale ID:  1033
    Additional Information 1:   0a9e
    Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
    Additional Information 3:   0a9e
    Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try searching the web? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443076/android-emulator-crashes-on-ig4icd32-dll-with-exception-code-c0000005-emulator

Comment: have you tried making another emulator?..

Answer (score 5):

AVD manager -> select your AVD -> click Edit -> Uncheck Use Host GPU
worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the amount of RAM configured for the Android Virtual Device.

Android Virtual Device Manager->Select AVD->Edit->Memory Options->

Answer (score 0):

**Its beacause of may be RAM error. Do this. This work for me.**

1. Close emulator
2. Go into AVD folder (eg. C:\Users\username.android\avd\phone.avd)
3. open config.ini file

   modify disk.dataPartition.size from M to MB, suppose its value is 512M then change it to 512MB

   do same for hw.ramSize from 512M to 512MB

   If you have storage sd card then also change sdcard.size from 10M to 10MB
4. Start emulator again. You must do this for all your emulators.