# AVD not launching

Tags: windows, android-emulator

The system configuration I am using is as following:

```
OS - Windows 7 (64 bit)
RAM - 8GB
Eclipse - Kepler release
Java - 1.6.0_45 (64 bit)
Android SDK - 22.2.1
ADT - 22.2.1.v201309180102-833290
Graphics Card - Intel(R) HD Graphics 400, version - 8.15.10.2696
```

When I create a new AVD and launch it an error always comes up - 'emulator-arm.exe has stopped working' - with the following details:

```
Problem signature:
    Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
    Application Name:   emulator-arm.exe
    Application Version:    0.0.0.0
    Application Timestamp:  5238f89b
    Fault Module Name:  ig7icd32.dll
    Fault Module Version:   0.0.0.0
    Fault Module Timestamp: 4f67b1c8
    Exception Code: c0000005
    Exception Offset:   000256e6
    OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
    Locale ID:  16393
    Additional Information 1:   0a9e
    Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
    Additional Information 3:   0a9e
    Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I have gone through various other questions addressing this issue as following:

[emulator.exe has stop working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967884/emulator-exe-has-stop-working)

[Error Message: emulator-arm.exe has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855877/error-message-emulator-arm-exe-has-stopped-working)

[emulator-arm.exe has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806841/emulator-arm-exe-has-stopped-working)

I have tried all the following options suggested by them:

1. Change the RAM value - I have tried with all values ranging from 256 to 1907
2. Change the target - Have tried the versions from 4.1.2, 4.2.2, 4.2 along with their Google APIs
3. Change the device - Have tried with various versions of Nexus along with WSVGA
4. Change the Heap - Have tried with different values of Heap size
5. Change the resolution - Have tried with various resolutions as per the device

But every time, for every new AVD, as soon as I launch it, I am getting the same error - 'emulator-arm.exe has stopped working' - with exactly the same Problem Signature as shared above.

Could someone point me in the right direction that how can this be resolved?

**UPDATE:** I invoked Android Debug Monitor to view the LogCat when the device is being launched but there are no log messages getting displayed there.

Any suggestions anyone on how to resolve this?

Comment: What is your graphics display driver?

Comment: It is Intel(R) HD Graphics 400, version - 8.15.10.2696, updated the question too with this detail.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off the "Use host GPU" option. Perhaps your computer's GPU is not compatible with the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a compatibility problem with the Intel HD Graphics driver. I would suggest you to update the driver to the latest available version and check.

Comment: I updated the driver and found that its already the latest one. Still getting the same error of AppCrash. Any other suggestions?